# .exe made from C++ works on command line but not from Java

Tags: java, exe

I have a .exe which mutes my windows computer. It is compiled from a C++ program. When I run this .exe from the command line, it works great, muting or unmuting my computer. However, I'm trying to run this from a Java program and I get no error, but it also doesn't actually run, or at least not properly since the volume is not toggled. I've been poking around to see what it could be and nothing obvious since the call to execute the .exe returns 0 and no errors.

Any thoughts would be helpful. Thank you.

Here's the c++ code which is compiled into "mute.exe":

```
  void VolumeControl::mute() {
        HWND hwnd = GetConsoleWindow();
        SendMessage(hwnd, WM_APPCOMMAND, (WPARAM)hwnd, APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_MUTE << 16);
    }
```

Here's the java code that calls it (I've tried using runtime exec as well as process builder):

```
 Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mute.exe");
 int exitVal = p.waitFor();
 System.out.println(exitVal);
 //Process process = new ProcessBuilder("mute.exe", "-u").start();
 //Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime() ;
 //rt.exec("mute.exe");
```

Comment: Note, I also tried doing all this with JNA and had what looks like the same output.  The Java program could see the C++ method and invoke it, but there was no change to the system. Using a .exe seemed like it might be easier since it clearly works on the command line but there must be a deeper issue here.

Comment: A GUI application does not have a console window by default.  Is mute.exe complied as a console app so it does get a console window?

Comment: Try "cmd /c mute.exe"

Comment: *Where* is `mute.exe` located?

Comment: Have you tried using GetLastError after the GetConsoleWindow and SendMessage calls to check for errors?

Comment: chrylis, I know it can find mute.exe because if I change the name it throws an error.

Comment: Dave, can you describe that further? The console window part is in the .exe code. I can just double click that .exe and it works fine. It's only when I call it from my java program that there is an issue.

Comment: groovy, cmd /c did not change the response.